# What is the best way to handle the keyboard in react native forms? Mine keeps hiding / showing and is distracting

Tags: javascript, android, forms, reactjs, react-native

I feel like this is a super easy thing but for some reason it's just not working like I think it should.

I have a small form with two fields (username & password) and a log in button.

When the user focuses into the first field the keyboard appears and they can edit that input.

When going to the next field, if the user presses the "return/next" key on the device's keyboard it focuses right away on the second input (which is fine).

However, if the user instead just taps on the next input field, the keyboard closes. **I want it to stay open.**

Also, when the user is done filling out the form, **I want them to be able to just tap on the "log In" button once and have the form submit** ... but right now if you do that the keyboard just disappears, and you have to tap the log in button again.

How can I get a better, less jarring keyboard experience here?

Below is my code:

```
return (
  <ScrollView
    style={styles.container}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" // I've also tried "handled" here, and also taking this attribute off all together
  >
    <View style={styles.modalHeaderBox}>
      <Text style={styles.modalHeader}>Log In</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.form}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TextInput
          ref="username"
          value={username}
          editable={editable}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          keyboardType="email-address"
          returnKeyType="next"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onSubmitEditing={() => this.refs.password.focus()}
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TextInput
          ref="password"
          value={password}
          editable={editable}
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          keyboardType="default"
          returnKeyType="go"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          secureTextEntry
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          onSubmitEditing={this.handlePressLogin}
          placeholder="Password"
        />
      </View>

      <View style={[styles.loginRow]}>
        <ButtonCTA
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onPress={this.handlePressLogin}
        >
          Log In
        </ButtonCTA>
      </View>
    </View>

  </ScrollView>
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the images/screenshots?

Comment: I can later, but would that really change anything?

Comment: It will help to understand the problem. I tested your code on iOS Simulator and it's working fine. Keyboard not closing when tapping password field after typing the username

Comment: @akshaygore Screenshot added. This is Android. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your input component props

```
blurOnSubmit={false}
```